# How to repeat objects with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm new to Angular and need to repeat objects until the data is exhausted.

Here's the code snippet that I wish to repeat.

```
        <!-- Start box content -->
        <div class='span3 box box-nomargin' style="margin-left: 0px !important;">

            <!-- Now starts the box content -->
            <div class='box-header red-background'>
                <div class="title text-center span12" style="font-weight: 600;">Skyfall</div>
                <div class="normal text-center span12 utilMonSmallTitle">Network:&nbsp;<span class="utilMonSmallText">My First Network</span></div>
                <div class="normal text-center span12 utilMonSmallTitle">Site:&nbsp;<span class="utilMonSmallText">My Site 388_ascdaaf298</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class='box-content text-center' style="padding-bottom: 0px;">

                <!-- Start box content Header -->
                <div class="title span4 text-left" style="color: black; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: -5px;">Hardware</div>
                <div class="title span3 text-center" style="color: black; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: -10px;">
                    <i id="icon508Compliant" class="icon-remove-sign" style="font-size: 40px; color: red;"></i>
                    <!-- The icons are: icon-remove-circle, icon-warning-sign, icon-ok-circle -->
                </div>
                <div class="title span4 text-right" style="color: black; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: -5px;">Software</div><br><br>
                <!-- End box content Header -->
                <!-- Start box content body -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <span style="font-size:24px; font-weight: bold; border-right: solid black 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 5px;">
                            <span id="hwVal1">{{hardwareAlerts[0].critical}}</span>
                        </span>
                        <span style="font-size:24px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px;">
                            <span id="hwVal2">{{hardwareAlerts[0].warning}}</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <span style="font-size:24px; font-weight: bold; border-right: solid black 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 5px;">
                            <span id="swVal1">{{softwareAlerts[0].critical}}</span>
                        </span>
                        <span style="font-size:24px; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 8px;">
                            <span id="swVal2">{{softwareAlerts[0].warning}}</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- End box content Body -->

                <!-- Start box content footer buttons -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <button class="btn btn-small btnBoxLeft"><i class="icon-warning-sign">View Critical</i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-small btnBoxRight"><i class="icon-warning-sign">View All</i></button>
                </div>
                <!-- End box content footer buttons -->

            </div>
            <!-- Now ends the box content -->                
        </div>
        <!-- End box content -->
```

So that whole snippet of code will REPEAT within a FLATTY Bootstrap "ROW" until there's no more data.

I'm used to Handlebars.js but Angular is a little tricky.

It needs to repeat based on the number of NETWORKS there are.

For instance:  If there are 10 networks, the above code should repeat 10 times displaying 10 BOXES.

I have my controllers and directives code working... just need to understand the "REPEAT" stuff.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-repeat`

```
<div class='span3 box box-nomargin' style="margin-left: 0px !important;" ng-repeat="object in objects">
```

Where in the above snippet `objects` would be your ARRAY of objects. If you only have an object and you wish to iterate keys, use `ng-repeat="(k, v) in objects"`. (Where `k` is your property name and `v` is the value of said property)

To display the data, simply reference the property within the repeater where you wish to use it via:

```
{{object.PROPERTY}}
```

Or, if using the `(k, v) in objects` simply do `{{k}}` or `{{v}}`